# MEAN Stack - Update route not posting correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have built a mean app but am having an issue with it posting a number value. I'm not sure if it is a mongoose validation error but for some reason mongoose can not upsert the number value but will when it is a string.

Here's the route:

```
//Edit A Site
router.put('/api/sites/:site_id', function(req, res) {

  Site.findById(req.params.site_id, function(err, site) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
        if(req.body.ip) site.ip = req.body.ip;
        if(req.body.domain) site.domain = req.body.domain;
        if(req.body.wp) site.wp = req.body.wp;
        if(req.body.host_name) site.host_name = req.body.host_name;
        if(req.body.hosted) site.hosted = req.body.hosted;
        console.log(req.body);
      // save the site
      site.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
          res.send(err);

          res.json(site);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The console.log has the full request body:
`{ hosted: 1, host_name: 'sup', wp: 'n/a' }`

But this is the mongoose response: `Mongoose: sites.update({ _id: ObjectId("57a16c4a7f7e5b7a7e1f5ad1") }, { '$set': { host_name: 'sup', wp: 'n/a' } })`

Schema:

```
// grab the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a schema
var sitesEntrySchema = new Schema({
    ip: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    domain: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    wp: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    host_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    hosted: {
      type: Number,
      min: 0,
      max: 1,
      required: true
    }
});

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
var Site = mongoose.model('Site', sitesEntrySchema);
module.exports = Site;
```

**EDIT:** 
I believe I found the solution. When checking for the req.body.hosted, because it is a number it fails. I had to update to check for undefined:

`if(req.body.hosted != undefined) site.hosted = req.body.hosted;`

Comment: Can you share your Site Schema?

Comment: Hey @dyouberg. Edited and added my schema. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Where are you getting that Mongoose response from?  Is that the error in your save's callback function?

Comment: @dyouberg I believe that's from the debug mode: `mongoose.set('debug', true)`

Comment: Did you try doing a findOneAndUpdate instead of findById + save in the callback function?

Comment: @dyouberg yes, this seems to be working better! Thank you. How can I insert only if it is new data? So only if request body has data in it for each param? Like if ip is empty don't insert.

Comment: You can probably just pass req.body into the findOneAndUpdate call if all of its members match your schema accordingly since req.body is just a JSON representation of what you are trying to pass in - or build an array off of the variables similar to what you did in your else statement so that you guarantee nothing foreign makes its way into your database.  
Another option is to use some form of body parsing middleware to check your request body prior to performing an update.